# Discord.py not sending message with on_message event

Tags: discord.py

So I've been working on my bot with discord.py and it's been working, but when I woke up this morning it wasn't sending any messages but it did every other function. I can't spot the error. It is supposed to respond and change member roles but only the roles change. The bot will not send the embed in the chat. The error is in the image. If anyone is able to find my error it would be greatly appreciated.

```py
if "sign" in message.content:
    if message.channel.id == 920821651627712514:
      signer=message.author
      signee=message.mentions[0].mention
      signeeid=message.mentions[0].id
      server=bot.get_guild(920821650096812063)
      teamsidslist=[920821650180694104]
      teamnames=['Philadelphia Eagles']
      teamemojis=['AFREagles']
      FO = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650285539374)
      GM = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650285539373)
      HC = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650285539372)
      staffroles = [FO, GM, HC]
      FA = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650180694097)
      Suspended = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=920821650159702055)
      roster=[]
      agency=[]
      teams=[]
      for rolesids in message.author.roles:
        if rolesids.id in teamsidslist:
          teams.append(rolesids.id)
          step2=str(teams)
          step3=step2.replace("[","")
          step4=step3.replace("]","")
          print(step4)
          step5=teamsidslist.index(int(step4))
          print(step5)
          emote=discord.utils.get(server.emojis,name=teamemojis[step5])
          teamname=teamnames[step5]
          team = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles,id=int(step4))
      for agents in server.members:
        if FA in agents.roles:
          agency.append(agents.id)
      if signeeid not in agency:
          embedno = discord.Embed(title="Transaction Failed!", description=None, color=discord.Color.red())
          embedno.add_field(name="This Transaction Couldn't Be Completed.", value="This player is signed already! Have them demand from their team or get released.")
          await message.channel.send(embed=embedno)
      elif FO in message.author.roles:
        for guys in server.members:
          if guys.id==signeeid:
            await guys.add_roles(team)
            await guys.remove_roles(FA)
            if Suspended in guys.roles:
              await message.channel.send("This player is signable, but is ineligible as they are suspended.")
        roster.append(guys)
        roster_size=str(len(roster))
        SignEmbed= discord.Embed(title="AFR Transactions", description=None, color=discord.Color.green())
        SignEmbed.add_field(name='Successful Transaction.', value=signee+" has been signed to the "+str(emote)+" "+teamname+" by "+signer+"!")
        SignEmbed.add_field(name="Roster Size is now ", value=roster_size+'/24', inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(embed=SignEmbed)
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1):

The `signer` variable is a `discord.Member` object and you can't concatenate `discord.Member` to string, i.e (discord.Member + "some string")

also concatenation makes code unreadable and are slow as well. Use f-strings instead.

here is an example:

```py
nice = 3
some_variable = "one two " + str(nice) + " we continue"
print(some_variable)
>>> one two 3 we continue


nice = 3
some_variable = f"one two {nice} we continue"
print(some_variable)
>>> one two 3 we continue
```

For your issue, just cast signer as string, i.e str(signer)

but I do highly recommend for you to switch to f-strings instead of using concatenation